# Does removing a struct from a vector, deconstruct it?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have this struct here with the vector

```
//Record Structure
struct Record {
    std::string date;
    std::string name;
    int dollars = 0;
    int cents = 0;

    std::string getCost() {
        //Dollars First
        std::stringstream dollar;
        dollar << dollars;
        std::string DOLLAR = dollar.str();

        //Cents Second
        std::stringstream cent;
        cent << cents;
        std::string CENT = cent.str();

        //Display cents as double zeros
        DOLLAR = DOLLAR.length() == 1 ? "0" + DOLLAR : DOLLAR;
        CENT = CENT.length() == 1 ? "0" + CENT : CENT;

        //Result
        std::string result = "$" + DOLLAR + "." + CENT;

        //Return
        return result;
    }

    void Constructor(std::string NM, std::string DT, int DOLLAS, int PENNY) {
        name = NM;
        date = DT;
        dollars = DOLLAS;
        cents = PENNY;
    }
};

//Vector that holds instances of the Record structure
std::vector <Record> Records;
```

Say I have already appended an instance to the vector

```
Record newInstance;
newInstance.Constructor("Name", "Date", 10, 0);

Records.push_back(newInstance);
```

If I erased it like so, will the whole structure be deconstructed and free up space?

```
Records.erase(Records.begin());
```

If it doesn't get deconstructed and free up space, how would I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when an element is removed from a vector, it is destroyed, and any resources it held should be freed.  I say "should" because this depends on proper implementation of the element type--we have to assume the element type is implemented such that destroying it does not leak any resources.

In your particular case, `Record` is a struct containing integers and `std::string`s, and this will work as you expect: removing a `Record` from a vector (or any  other STL container) will free the memory used by the integers and strings.

Comment: How you you properly implement an elements type, will you please explain?

Comment: @Skelelele probably by implementing a constructor and a destructor. Read a little bit more about the RAII idiom and you will understand more about objects and how to work with them in C++.

Comment: @Skelelele: You just make sure that destroying your element doesn't leak anything.  Your `Record` is properly implemented already, because it does not use any pointers.

Comment: @John Zwinck Thank you my kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What `std::vector::erase` does is

> Reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed.

You can find the reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).